# Failed to create citext column with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

As the tile says I'm trying to create a table with one column as citext.

I have manually created the extension on the database.

I can create a table with success directly from PSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test (nickname citext PRIMARY KEY, full_name TEXT NOT NULL);
```

The above SQL works.

However, whenever I try to execute the same SQL with a psycopg2 connection, it fails with:

```
type "citext" does not exist
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE test (nickname citext PRIMARY KEY, full_nam...
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Output of \dT citext:

```
      List of data types
 Schema |  Name  | Description
--------+--------+-------------
 public | citext |
(1 row)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Here's the manual creation process from PSQL:

```
mydb=> \d
No relations found.
mydb=> CREATE TABLE test (nickname citext PRIMARY KEY, full_name TEXT NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE
mydb=> \d
       List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner
--------+------+-------+--------
 sentry | test | table | sentry
(1 row)

mydb=> \d test
      Table "sentry.test"
  Column   |  Type  | Modifiers
-----------+--------+-----------
 nickname  | citext | not null
 full_name | text   | not null
Indexes:
    "test_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (nickname)
```

And here's the python script:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "mydb", user = "sentry", password = "...", host = "...", port = "5432")
except Exception as err:
    print(err)

cur = conn.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute("SET search_path TO sentry")
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (nickname citext PRIMARY KEY, full_name TEXT NOT NULL);")
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `\dT citext` run from psql?

Comment: @AdamKG added the output in the OP. Also, just to confirm, both the commands are run on the same schema.

Comment: Are you wanting the create the test table in the public schema or the sentry schema?
This is probably the source of the problem `SET search_path TO sentry`

Comment: Have you run something like `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext WITH SCHEMA public;` before creating the table?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

- You created the extension in a schema that is not on your `search_path` in the psycopg2 connection.
- You are connecting to different databases (perhaps you created the extension in `postgres`).

Comment: Answering your possibilities: 1) I didn't specify the schema for the extension, but AFAIK they're schemaless. If they were not, then I would not be able to execute the SQL directly in PSQL, right? 2) I've run the same SQL from python but replacing citext with text, and the table is created in the expected schema.

Comment: Added both creation processes. Note that they run on the same schema.

Comment: Your edits show that the solution is my answer number one. You set the `search_path` to `sentry`, so you shouldn't be surprised that `public` is not on it. Schema-qualify the type: `public.citext`.